# Jest: How to mock the methods of an esModule?

Tags: javascript, typescript, unit-testing, jestjs, mocking

I have a simple function that use the library [jszip](https://github.com/Stuk/jszip) to zip some folders and files:

```js
// app.ts
const runJszip = async (): Promise<void> => {
  const zip = new Jszip();

  zip.folder('folder')?.file('file.txt', 'just some text');
  zip.file('file.txt', 'just some text');

  await zip.generateAsync({ type: 'blob' });
};
```

I want to test it by spying the methods `folder` and `file`. I used for that the [mocking partial](https://jestjs.io/docs/28.x/mock-functions#mocking-partials) strategy to handle the default export of this library:

```js
// app.test.ts
import { runJszip } from './app';

const mockFile = jest.fn();
const mockFolder = jest.fn();

const mockJszip = jest.fn().mockImplementation(() => {
  return {
    folder: mockFolder,
    file: mockFile,
  };
});

jest.mock('jszip', () => {
  return jest.fn().mockImplementation(() => ({
    __esModule: true,
    default: mockJszip,
  }));
});

test('jszip', async () => {
  await runJszip();

  expect(mockFile).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(2);
  expect(mockFolder).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1);
});
```

Unfortunately, it seems that I can't properly mock the `folder` method as you can see in the following error message:

```
    Message:
      zip.folder is not a function

      4 |   const zip = new Jszip();
      5 |
    > 6 |   zip.folder('folder')?.file('file.txt', 'just some text');
```

So does someone have an idea how I could mock and spy on this method?

Have a look at the [minimal reproducible example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/webpack-5-react-starter-hy8tyu?file=src/app.test.ts).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have it working as expected by making `mockFolder` in [@bln's response](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74553158/8352929) returning a mocked Jszip instance:

```
import { runJszip } from './app';

const mockFile = jest.fn();
let mockFolder: jest.Mock;

function mockJszip() {
  mockFolder = mockFolder ?? jest.fn(mockJszip);
  return {
    folder: mockFolder,
    file: mockFile,
    generateAsync: jest.fn(),
  };
}

jest.mock('jszip', () => {
  return {
    __esModule: true,
    default: mockJszip,
  };
});

test('jszip', async () => {
  await runJszip();

  expect(mockFile).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(2);
  expect(mockFolder).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1);
});
```

https://stackblitz.com/edit/webpack-5-react-starter-ofxcmy?file=src/app.test.ts

Answer (score 3):

```
import { runJszip } from './app';

const mockFile = jest.fn();
const mockFolder = jest.fn();

function mockJszip() {
  return {
    folder: mockFolder,
    file: mockFile,
    generateAsync: jest.fn(),
  };
}

jest.mock('jszip', () => {
  return {
    __esModule: true,
    default: mockJszip,
  };
});

test('jszip', async () => {
  await runJszip();

  expect(mockFile).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(2);
  expect(mockFolder).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1);
});
```

For the `?.file()` chaining, maybe with some `mockImplementation` around `mockJszip`

Comment: Thanks for the proposition! Would you have an idea how to handle `?.file()` to make the test pass?

Comment: @bln you need to make `mockFolder` return a `Jszip` instance with the same `mockFile` func to make all tests pass. See my answer and if you want to update yours... all credits should go to you.